# Autowiring not working outside controller

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, autowired

I am using autowiring in one of my projects. `@autowiring` is working fine in the controller, but I need to use same autowiring object in some other class, which is used as task class for quartz. Autowiring is not working there.

I tried this code listed below, but it did not succeed. In all attempts it's getting `null` for `readXmlDao`.

```
@Repository("updateTeam")
public class TeamUpdate {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("readXmlDao")
    ReadXmlDao readXmlDao;
```

Please suggest a solution, thanks.

Comment: do you have two seperate projects? how do you include the spring context.xml?

Comment: Is the class TeamUpdate in the same project as your controller? Or does your <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.here" /> covers your TeamUpdate class?

Comment: Is quartz instantiating the TeamUpdate class? Spring auto wiring would only work if spring actually instantiates the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowire works in spring context (class instances managed by spring). Quartz creates its own contexts (creates its own instances). Spring do not have to know about these classes and its why autowires not working on them.

It is more spring/quartz configuration issue, than class annotation issue.

Answer (score 1):

Spring will **never** leave an `@Autowired` target `null`. If it's processing the bean and can't find a match it will throw exceptions.

Since you are telling us it's `null`, the only possibility is that Spring is **not** managing your object. You're either creating a `TeamUpdate` object manually or some other process (not Spring) is creating it for you.

Comment: Thank You :) , You saved my hours.

Comment: @Vivek [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) a more comprehensive post.

Answer (score 0):

In your spring-servlet file make sure you are scanning the correct packages.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your package here"/>
```

A lot of times you might have your controllers and your repositories in different packages.  Make sure to scan both.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this approach for using spring managed beans in a non-spring managed object.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/using-spring-managed-bean-in-non-managed-object.html